# Trying to aggregate ReactionTypes in R

Tags: r

sample of outAct

```
Activity      ReactionType      numberActivities

activator     activates         16
binding       binds             83
recombinase   binds             1
branching     branches          3
carboxylase   carboxylates      36
peptidase     cleaves           425
endopeptidase cleaves           368
nuclease      cleaves           53
glycosylase   cleaves           24
cyclase       converts          12
transhydrogenase converts       3
hist deacetylase deacetylates   8
deacetylase   deacetylates      16
```

I want to count all the same ReactionTypes and sum up their numberActivities

```
reaction_types <-aggregate(numberActivities ~ ReactionType, unique(outAct), FUN=sum)
```

Desired output

```
ReactionType    number

activates       16
binds           84
branches        3
carboxylates    36
cleaves         870
converts        15
deacetylates    24
```

Problem is, I’m getting duplicates, i.e. they are not being counted as one unique ReactionType e.g. the output contains rows such as

```
deacetylates    8
deacetylates    16
```

There are more examples like this throughout the output file.
Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do your strings have whitespace in them?

Comment: What is the output from `as.character(unique(outAct$ReactionType))`?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
outAct %>% group_by(ReactionType) %>% summarise(number = sum(numberActivities))
```

Comment: Alistaire, how do I check for whitespaces?

Comment: Jean, I don't understand your comment. Do you mean in the aggregate function above? The output is from this function acting on outAct

Comment: Adiana, the library dplyr doesn't seem to work in my environment and it doesn't recognise the statement                                                                      out %>% group_by(ReactionType) %>% summarise(number = sum(numberActivities))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'out' not found

Comment: How do strip out white space from my outAct$ReactionType column?

Comment: paste(reaction_types)                                                                                               [1] "c(\"phosphorylates  \", \"cleaves  \", \"transfers \", \"transports  \", \"hydrolyses  \", \"dephosphorylates  \", \"reduces  \", \"dehydrogenates  \", \"ligates  \", \"exchanges (nucleotide)\", \"clamp loader binds\", \"exchanges  (nucleotide)\", \"binds  \", etc etc                                                                              This is the problem, some have space and backslash, others just a backslash. How do I clean this up?

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED! One of my input files I read into the script had whitespaces which I removed with strip.white=TRUE. The aggregate function now works as I intended it to. Thanks!